# Response function in plasma

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, plasma-physics

I am reading an article where authors investigate how a particular type of electrostatic waves propagates in a plasma. They start with the Poisson's equation in the next form:

$$\nabla^2 \phi(r,\omega) = \rho(r,\omega)/\epsilon_0,$$

where $\phi$ is the potential, $$\rho(r,\omega) = \int g(r,r',t)\phi(r',\omega)dr'$$ is the charge density expressed through a response function $g(r,r',\omega)$. 
**I have difficulties with finding this response function in terms of the dielectric or conductivity tensors.**

**Remark I**: in plasma physics we know that the conductivity tensor $\bar \sigma$ relates the current density and the electric field as follows: 
$\vec j(r,\omega) = \int \bar \sigma(r,r',\omega)\vec E(r')dr'$.

**Remark II**: The article I am trying to get through is *"Electron Bernstein waves in the mid-plane region of a spherical tokamak"*. They authors investigate how EBW propate using ray-tracing techniques and in the second part of the article they solve the full-wave equation (which I wrote above).

**Attempt to derive eq. 17 from the article**:
As it was mentioned the answer is given by eq. 17 from the article. But I would like to understand how it was derived. Here is what I've got:

---

Starting with Fourier transforms of the continuity equation and the Ohm's law:

$\omega \rho +  \vec k \cdot \vec j = 0$ - continuity eq.

$\vec j = \bar \sigma(\omega,\vec k) \cdot \vec E = i \bar \sigma(\omega,\vec k) \cdot \vec k \phi$ -  Ohm's law where the electric field expressed through $\nabla \phi$

Multiplying the last equation by $\vec k$ we get:
$\vec k\cdot \vec j =  i  \vec k \cdot \bar \sigma(\omega,\vec k) \cdot \vec k \phi$

Substituting this expression into the continuity equation and expressing $\rho$ as the function of $\phi$ we get:
$\rho = \frac{1}{4\pi} (k^2 - \vec k \cdot \bar \epsilon \cdot \vec k )$

Then taking the inverse Fourier transform we get an answer which is similar to the one from the article. But $\vec k \cdot \bar \epsilon \cdot \vec k = 0$ in the electrostatic approximation (it is essentially dispersion relation for the these types of waves)

Comment: I believe your formula for the response is the other way around, because as it is currently written the answer is quite easy ($g=\nabla^2\delta(r-r')$, because $\int\nabla^2\delta(r-r')\phi(r')=\int\delta(r-r')\nabla^2\phi(r')=\nabla^2\phi$). I believe you want $\phi(r)=\int g(r,r')\rho(r')$, in which case $g$ is just a Green function (=response function). If this is right, then what you want to do is to find the Green function for the Laplace operator, which is explained in many pages online.

Comment: I see what you mean. The problem is that we don't know the charge density $\rho$. It depends on how plasma responds to the potential (or electric field). It has to be find as the integral above using  the response function $g(r,r',\omega)$. You can also call $g(r,r',\omega)$ susceptibility.

Comment: so you mean $\rho$ is unknown, and $\phi$ is known?

Comment: Both functions are unknown. What we know is how the plasma reacts on the applied electric field (or potential). So the function $g(r,r',\omega)$ is supposed to be known. And we end up with the integro-differtential equation above.

Comment: I'm not gonna pretend I know about plasma physics. I don't know anything about it (as you may have already noted by my comments above). I hope someone here can help!

Comment: No problem. Your help is appreciated anyway.

Comment: @Kirill - To what article are you referring?  It might help me answer your question if I see these functions in context.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Nice to see plasma physicist here. I added the "remark II" to the question. If you need more details please let me know.

Comment: @Kirill - It looks like your question is answered in Equation 17, is it not?  Then you just follow the text in the next few paragraphs and they give you a linearized version of the dielectric tensor (they call it a function, but it should be a tensor to be correct).  You can also look up the general warm plasma dispersion relation for electrostatic waves to get $\varepsilon \left( \mathbf{n} \right)$ in various forms...

Comment: @Kirill - Then I think the rest is just the usual symbol gymnastics...  [P.S.  I am not a fan of their use of $\rho$ as both a scalar for number density and a relative position vector as it lends to trivial mistakes that can cause significant headaches for readers...]

Comment: @honeste_vivere you are right the answer is given by eq.17. But I would like to understand how it was derived. I edited my question to specify in more details where the problem is.

Comment: Which article ?

Comment: the name of the article  specified in the Remark II